# Django models, set unqiue attribute for M2M field per object

Tags: python, django, postgresql, django-models, django-rest-framework

Currently, have a database with an Item table and a Stock table. There is a many to many relationship between the two. A single item object can have many sizes. The next step is to assign an 'inStock' options to the item per size. 
Any thoughts on acheiving this?

Current models.py

```
class Stock(models.Model):
    size = models.CharField(max_length=30)
    stock = models.BooleanField(default=False)
    def __str__(self):
        return self.size

class Item(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField(max_length=250, null=True, unique=True)
    price = models.DecimalField(max_digits=8, decimal_places=2)
    aw_product_id = models.CharField(max_length=11, null=True) # Removed because multiple products has similar identifer
    url = models.URLField(max_length=250)           # Removed 'unique=True'as the aw_prod_id will throw an integrity error
    image = models.CharField(max_length=1000)
    retailer = models.CharField(max_length=250)
    category = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    featured = models.CharField(max_length=10, default='NO')
    gender = models.CharField(max_length=100, null=True)
    sizes = models.ManyToManyField(Stock)
    uniq_id = models.CharField(max_length=11, null=True, unique=True) # Removed because multiple products has similar identifer

    def __str__(self):
        return self.title
```

Comment: [Extra fields on many-to-many relationships](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/topics/db/models/#intermediary-manytomany)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the `through` argument to ManyToManyField to specify another model to use for the relationship, with additional fields instead of the autogenerated model that django creates by default.

Comment: Any opinions on how I should arrange this with my view? Thanks

Comment: You'd just create/delete your intermediate model the way you would any other model.  https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/db/models/#extra-fields-on-many-to-many-relationships